# IServiceCollection cannot resolve type when loaded from an outside assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I'm running into a strange issue using dependency injection, adding in a Singleton for a type that comes from an outside assembly.  This is using the Azure Function framework, but I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it or if this would repro with ASP.NET Core as well.  My actual "real world" implementation is far, far too complicated to outline here, but I've managed to come up with a minimal repro.

### BugRepro.dll (This is a Azure Function project)

This has two files.

Test.cs:

```
public class Test
{
    private readonly AppConfig config;

    public Test(AppConfig config)
    {
        this.config = config;
    }

    [FunctionName("Test")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RunAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
    {
        return new OkObjectResult(config.SampleSetting);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
namespace BugRepro
{
    public class AppConfig
    {
        public string SampleSetting { get; set; } = "Test";
    }

    public static class Startup
    {
        public static void Configure(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton(new AppConfig());
        }
    }
}
```

This assembly has a reference to `TestDll.dll`.

### TestDll.dll (This is a normal .NET Core library)

Startup.cs:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(TestDll.Startup))]
namespace TestDll
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var asm = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.Combine(builder.GetContext().ApplicationRootPath, @"bin\BugRepro.dll"));
            var type = asm.GetType("BugRepro.Startup");
            var method = type.GetMethod("Configure");
            method.Invoke(null, new object[] {builder.Services});
        }
    }
}
```

When the Azure Function runs, the `TestDll.Startup.Configure` method is automatically called by the framework.  This method loads the other assembly, `BugRepro.dll` using reflection and calls the `BugRepro.Startup.Configure` static method, passing the `IServiceCollection`.

The `BugRepro.Startup.Configure` static method adds a single instance of `AppConfig` to the service collection.  I can verify the instance has successfully been added to the service collection, and stepping all the way into the code, the right ServiceDescriptor and everything has been created.  Everything appears perfect.

However, when I call the `/Test` endpoint, I get the error:

```
[2021-02-04T06:39:10.502Z] Executed 'Test' (Failed, Id=22cfb587-3ba9-401f-b0a5-8688aed7bc9d, Duration=386ms)
[2021-02-04T06:39:10.506Z] Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions: Unable to resolve service for type 'BugRepro.AppConfig' while attempting to activate 'BugRepro.Test'.
```

Basically, it acts like the Singleton has never been registered and it cannot resolve that type.

### Ways to fix:

So, if I move the `AppConfig` class from the BugRepro.dll to TestDll.dll (basically the AppConfig type is in the same DLL as my `FunctionsStartup` class), the code works as expected.

Another way to fix it is to use an interface, which is defined in TestDll:

```
public interface IConfig
{
}
```

Then make `AppConfig` implement that interface, then register the Singleton using its interface:

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfig>(new AppConfig());
```

However, then I have to inject `IConfig` into the `Test` constructor rather than `AppConfig` which I do not want to do.

#### My Question

Is there a way to register a Singleton for a type that lives in an external assembly?  To me, this seems like a bug in the .NET Core DI framework.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is caused by your use of `Assembly.LoadFile`. The `LoadFile` method can cause the same assembly to be loaded twice in such way that the framework sees this as a totally different assembly, with different types.

The solution is to use `Asssembly.Load` instead:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("c:\..."));
```

See for instance this [related topic](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/assembly-loading-resolution-conflicts.html?highlight=loadfile#resolution-conflicts-caused-by-dynamic-assembly-loading) (for Simple Injector, but the problem is identical) for more information.

Comment: Nice!  You're absolutely right, that fixed it!  That was driving me crazy for 2 hours last night..

Comment: Time to start using a better DI Conrainer; one that actually would have reported what the problem was ;-)

Comment: I think you can use Autofac with ASP.NET Core, not sure if Azure Functions let you swap out the DI stuff..  Agree, it was near impossible to debug (I even spent some time digging into the service collection source code to no avail).  I doubt I would have ever been able to narrow down the exact problem on my own, I was considering redesigning the entire thing..

Comment: It's true that Azure Functions is very limited and doesn't expose the same type of extension points as ASP.NET Core does. Still, you can use any DI Container you would like, but you might need to take a different approach, such explained [here](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/536#issuecomment-382438219) on the Simple Injector forum.